# Doctrine Relationship not with Primary key

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

What I would like is to create a relationship `OneToMany` on 2 symfony entities on a specific value (Not on the ID).

This is what I tried:

```php
    class ClassA
    {
        ...

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ClassB", inversedBy="list")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="key_id")
         */
        private $classB;
    }

    class ClassB
    {
        ...

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\classA", mappedBy="classB")
         */
        private $list;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */
        private $keyId;
   }
```

This is my migration :

```php
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE class_a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D4FDD1F49D16CBF9 FOREIGN KEY (class_b_id) REFERENCES class_b (key_id)');
```

For me that's look right.
as the migration say the reference in `class_b` is `key_id`

But I get this issue message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE class_a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D4FDD1F49D16CBF9 FOREIGN KEY (class_b_id) REFERENCES class_b (keyId)':
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3734 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'key_id' for constraint 'FK_D4FDD1F49D16CBF9' in the referenced table 'class_b'

What do I made wrong?
What do I missed in the documentation?

Thank you for your help

**Edit 1**:

@spirit Thank you, I thing it's better with a `bigInt`. But that's change nothing...

```
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE class_b (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, key_id BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE class_a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D4FDD1F49D16CBF9 FOREIGN KEY (class_b_id) REFERENCES class_b (key_id)');
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that there is no `key_id` column in your `class_b`
have you tried to add `/** @Column(name="key_id") */` to your `$keyId` member ?

Comment: @PierrickRambaud Thank you for your answer. But I have still the same issue ...

Comment: ok second guess you're `$keyId` is not referenced as an `Id`, does * `@ORM\Id()` annotation change anything ?

Comment: the error says that you need an index ;) check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new column to your SQL table `class_b`. Something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE class_b ADD key_id BIGINT;
```

and add an index:

```sql
ALTER TABLE class_b ADD INDEX (key_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why I think:

[It's not yet supported...](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys)

Comment: hm. perhaps... but maybe you can give us your use case, so we can find the right solution?